# How to install Qt WebGL Pluggin

Tags: linux, qt

I am currently trying to install Qt WebGL so I can remotely access my raspberry pi on my virtual machine that runs Linux for Qt Creator with Qt version 5.11.3.

I am currently trying to install the plugin and follow the steps given on this website but I am having some trouble

Website being talked about: https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/11/23/qt-quick-webgl-release-512

I scroll down on the website and it says "How to use it, you only need to install it"

I can't seem to find that prompt to install it, does anyone have any ideas how I can install this plugin for Qt and does it even work with version 5.11.3?

One last thing, when it shows commands to type in, are those supposed to be typed into the terminal on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are the same as with any other Qt module (You must use the branch that is closest to your Qt version):

```
git clone -b 5.11 https://code.qt.io/qt/qtwebglplugin.git
cd qtwebglplugin
mkdir build && cd build
qmake ../
make
sudo make install
```